# jQuery redirect not working with localhost?

Tags: jquery

If I try to run `window.location.href = "www.example.com"`, redirect works fine. If I try to run `window.location.href = "localhost:8000/example"`, nothing happens. How do I fix this behavior?

**EDIT:** This redirect is inside of an AJAX success callback, if that makes any difference.

Comment: please add your console error

Comment: There is no console error.

Comment: what do you get? a 404 error or what?

Comment: try only location.href=URL

Comment: @SamGhatak Nothing happens.

Comment: @Yaseen That did not fix the issue, exact same behavior.

Comment: can you first hit the URL on a new tab and see what the behavior is

Comment: the url you trying in location.href= execute it in browser is it work

Comment: @SamGhatak `localhost:8000/example` loads a page fine when not redirected to with the above code.

Comment: What's example?? surely it would be **window.location.href = "example.php";**

Comment: @JordanLowe The page I'm interested in redirecting to is `localhost:8000/example`.

Comment: @Xenon and you're telling me this page is of no file type?

Comment: @JordanLowe `localhost:8000/example` is not a file, it is a URL. The redirect sends a GET request to `localhost:8000/example`, which returns a response that the browser reads and displays. If you'd like to read more about how this works, I'd recommend reading http://www.silicon-press.com/briefs/brief.http/brief.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `window.location.href = "//localhost:8000"`

Comment: Yep, so it ends up jQuery was confused because it didn't know which protocol to use. Prepending `https://` fixed the issue.